# What caused the changes in pronunciation of the hard "G" in "Los Angeles"?

Tags: pronunciation, historical-change

I know there was a long debate about whether "Los Angeles" should be pronounced like the English (soft-G, as in "jelly") or the Spanish (heavy-H as in "Jose"), and given the history of the city, that division seems quite natural and inevitable.
The English version eventually won, and except among Spanish speakers it is now the standard pronunciation.

> There was once heated debate over how to pronounce “Los Angeles.” The Spanish pronunciation of the name has long been “Loce AHN-heh-less.” Yet, non-Spanish speaking Angelenos seemed to prefer the harder-sounding anglicized version “Loss ANN-ju-less.” The anglicized version was adopted, in 1934, by the U.S. Board on Geographic Names.
> — [Pronouncing Los Angeles](http://www.laalmanac.com/geography/ge13c.php)

In many films from the 1940s and 1950s though, the city's name is frequently pronounced a third way, with a hard-G (as in "gelding" or "Geller").

But I can't find any reason for this pronunciation, with the hard-G, so when and why did the hard-G version originate, and when and why did it disappear?

Comment: Well, the Spanish doesn't have a /g/; it's /los 'aŋeles/, with the velar nasal sound of English _hang_, which also doesn't have a /g/ sound. That's just ordinary Spanish for 'the angels'. So, if you don't want to say the Spanish, what do you do with the G? Two possibilities -- stop /g/ or palatalized stop /dʒ/, as in _go_ and _Joe_, respectively. This kinda stuff happens all the time with English speakers adapting foreign words, especially since English spelling is so awful.

Comment: Native English speakers find it very difficult to pronounce *Los Angeles* the authentic Spanish way, so we're going to mispronounce it no matter what.

Comment: @JohnLawler Spanish does have a /g/ - it's pronounced [g] utterance-initially and [ɣ] in most other contexts. Spanish doesn't have a /ŋ/, and *ángel* is pronounced [ˈaŋxel] (or [ˈaŋhel] or [ˈanhel] in some dialects), which is phonemically /ˈanxel/.

Comment: As a city focused on the entertainment world for the last 100 years, Los Angeles is very prone to fads and fashions. I'd be interested if there is a more exact explanation, but there is likely to be some element of "somebody famous said it that way".

Comment: My grandfather was a native Angelino who grew up in the 1930s, a descendant of Swedish immigrants. He always pronounced Los Angeles with a hard /g/ sound: "Los An-ge-lees". I don't know why.

Comment: The g in Los Angeles in Spanish , the /x/ voiceless velar fricative, is completely pronounceable for English speakers, but they have to know it. If you can say **h**ead, you can say Los An**g**eles. Almost the same. But shucks, English speakers also pronounce the s in Paris, so them's the breaks.

Comment: I’m going to say it’s simply because it contains the word angel, in which everyone knows how to pronounce the ’g’, coupled with the inherent laziness of people faced with an unfamiliar but non-English word.

Comment: @CassLopez, but in the case asked in this question, they don't pronounce it as "angel", they pronounce it as "angle".

Comment: @RayButterworth Then maybe I just answered the second part of the final question “why did it disappear?” as well as the title.

Comment: @Lambie: if it's pronounceable, why do we say *lock* and not *loch*, *bahk* and not *Bach*, *Van Goff* and not *Van Gogh*, *Rockmaninoff* and not *Rachmaninoff* in English? (Okay ... maybe the Х in Russian cyrillic and the [x] in Mexican Spanish have softened to [h] sounds, but when did this happen? I definitely heard the unpronounceable [x] pronounced in *Los Angeles* when I lived in the LA area in the 1980s. And the English pronunciation was decided four decades before that.)

Comment: @PeterShor I have no idea. I am just saying that it's about not knowing rather than being impossible to pronounce for an English speaker. There are, of course, sounds an English speaker would have trouble with, for sure.  The Spanish pronunciation of Los Angeles is the same across all varieties of Spanish ....

Comment: @Lambie: there is a big difference between the sound [x] (as in *loch* and *Bach*) and the sound [h] (as in *haben* and *have*). German and Hebrew have both. Some varieties of Spanish have [x] in *Los Angeles*, which is unpronounceable for English speakers, and some varieties have [h].

Comment: @PeterShor I can categorically state that all Spanish speakers (from any part of the Spanish-speaking world) would say Los Angeles in **Spanish**, the same way. Just like they would say el general or la genética the same way.  Don't you believe me?

Comment: @Lambie: I don't know about you, but as a native speaker of American English, I hear a big difference in the /g/ in *Los Ángeles* between the speakers from Columbia and from Spain on [forvo.com](https://forvo.com/word/los_%C3%A1ngeles/#es). So, no I don't believe you; I believe my ears. These pronunciations may sound the same to you and to native Spanish speakers, but not to native English speakers.

Comment: PeterShor I have never, ever in all my born days heard anything like what you are saying. There are many, many differences in pronunciation in certain sounds, the ge of los generales and Los Angeles is simply not one of them. The difference is in the LOS, not in the angeles. The Spaniards pronounce LOS with a sh sound as in lush, the others all have a "clean" s as in loss. That is the difference, not the ge.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127215/discussion-between-peter-shor-and-lambie).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this 1953 article](https://doi.org/10.1179/nam.1953.1.1.35) by David Allen Stein, the pronunciation since the 1850 incorporation had been the one with soft G, and the hard-G variant was a pseudo-Spanish pronunciation that grew out of a "craze" around the turn of the century "to give every new street, every new subdivision, every new town a 'Spanish' name ... not limited to Southern California but spread over the state." If this is correct, the hard-G variant may be a sort of [hyperforeignism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperforeignism) on the assumption that that was closer to Spanish [ˈaŋxeles] (or whatever the Spanish pronunciation was thought to be).

This is given credence by [this letter](https://www.newspapers.com/clip/32760469/19080629losangeleslummis/) sent to a newspaper by [Charles Fletcher Lummis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Fletcher_Lummis), an LA librarian who [vigorously advocated](https://www.kcet.org/shows/lost-la/how-to-pronounce-los-angeles-according-to-charles-lummis) for the hard-G pronunciation:

> Spanish G before E has no precise equivalent in English. It is almost exactly the German ch in "buch." Those who call the name "Ann Hell" are less outlandish than the "angle" people; but they are still far from the fact.

So even though he was well aware that [ɡ] wasn't a good approximation to [x], he advocated for it anyway because it was at least closer than [dʒ].

The hard-G pronunciation soon lost favor, with endorsements of the soft G coming from the US Board on Geographic Names in 1934, and from the city of Los Angeles itself in 1952, as documented in [this *LA Times* story](https://www.latimes.com/local/la-xpm-2011-jun-26-la-me-0626-then-20110626-story.html). Again assuming Stein is correct, this was a return to an old form.

---

To address your question more directly, I think Stein and Lummis's accounts imply the hard-G pronunciation arose from an earlier, more faithful attempt at approximating Spanish, and [ɡ] was inserted as a result of [epenthesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epenthesis). Here's what I think happened:

- The Spanish [x] was approximated by /h/, but this was soon dropped as is common with /h/ occurring after stress and between voiced sounds (cf. *vehicle, Birmingham*).
- The second vowel in *Angeles* lenited to a schwa (if not already), which gave rise to either a syllabic realization of /əl/, i.e. [-ŋl̩-], or a complete elision of the vowel, i.e. [-ŋl-].
- Since [ŋl] is quite rare in existing words (cf. *angle, English*) except across morphological boundaries (*wrongly, meaningless*), [ɡ] was inserted.